# Explain why set of integers is complete

Tags: real-analysis

Given definition: An ordered set A is complete if it has the "least upper bound property" (completeness).

We are given $ \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}$ are complete.

and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete.

I understand the inf of the naturals is 1 and has no sup. not sure what the inf or sup of the integers is. For the rationals, I would appreciate any info here as well.

Comment: The LUBP says that every BOUNDED set has a least upper bound.

Comment: You are missunderstanding the definition having _the least upper bound property_ (LUBP). An ordered set $A$ have the LUBP if for every set with an upper bound there exist a supremum. In $\Bbb{N}$ the $\max$ works, in $\Bbb{Z}$ too. $\Bbb{Q}$ does not have this property since $\{x\mid x^2<2\}$ have an upper bound but not a supremum.

Comment: The example of @MrSelberg is very illustrative. Daceydark please notice that the reason why the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^{2} < 2 \}$ has no least upper bound is that $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Everybody is saying "set," which might be confusing. An ordered set $A$ has the LUBP if every **subset** of $A$ with an upper bound has a least upper bound.

Comment: Good point @ThomasAndrews. daveydark Take a subset of $\Bbb{Z}$ which have an **upper bound**. Can you find a least upper bound? How?

Comment: -5<x<5 lub:5 but it is not in the set.

Comment: The set $-5<x<5$ in $\Bbb{Z}$ have an upper bound, $5$ for example, and $4$ is the least upper bound. Since the set of $x$ such that $-5<x<5$ is $\{-4,-3,...,3,4\}$. Note that the LUB can be **outside** the subset, but if it **exist** in our ordered set then the subset have a LUB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important part of the least upper bound property for an ordered set $A$ is that if you start with *any subset* $X$ of $A$ (not just $A$ itself) that is bounded above, the supremum of $X$ must be an element of $A$.

$\mathbb{Z}$ has neither and infimum nor a supremum, but that is OK because any *bounded subset* of the integers has a largest element which is the set's supremum.

The rationals, on the other hand, do not have the property because it is possible to find a bounded subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ which has an irrational supremum. As an example you can take the set obtained by writing the first $n$ decimal places of $\pi$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$X= \{3.1, 3.14, 3.141,3.1415,\ldots\} $$

Since any number with a terminating decimal representation is rational, $X\subset\mathbb{Q}$. But $\sup X = \pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$ so $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the completeness of the definition of least upper bound property, you can only start with any **non-empty** subset *X* of *A* that is bounded above, as anything could be an upper bound of an empty set which can be proven by contradiction.